# How to increase speed of Matlab for gaussian fit, apart from chosing good starting conditions?

Tags: c++, matlab, gaussian

Can anyone help?

I work on detection of contour of red blood cells in phase contrast images. After transformation from Cartesian coordinate system into radial coordinate system I try to find exact contour position by Gaussian fit.
This results in 360 x frames Gaussian fits, which results in ~20 min of calculation time per image stack...way too long.
Is there a method to speed up the process or to outsource the problem to a c/c++ function?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways to call C/C++ functions directly from matlab.  Mex files, DLL's etc.  All are well documented in the Matlab documentation.  How fast do you need your computation to be?  Is there any redundancy between your images in a given image stack that you can exploit?

Comment: First step is to [`profile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) your code to determine which parts are most expensive and most deserving of optimization. Before you go to C/C++, do you even know if your current Matlab code is as efficient as it can be? Have you vectorized and are you using memory effectively?